# JasperReports 7.1.0 error installation in ubuntu 18.04 : BUILD FAILED the following error occured while executing import-export.xml

Tags: jasperserver

I'm installing JasperReports server 7.1.0 on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM machine.
I tried the bundle installation and the manual installation and getting the same error.
In the manual installation, I'm using:

- mysql 5.7
- Tomcat 8
- Java 8 (version "1.8.0_221")

Output:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
BUILD FAILED
/home/ranya/Téléchargements/TIB_js-jrs_7.1.0_bin/jasperreports-server-pro-7.1.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/db-common.xml:1373: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ranya/Téléchargements/TIB_js-jrs_7.1.0_bin/jasperreports-server-pro-7.1.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/import-export.xml:387: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ranya/Téléchargements/TIB_js-jrs_7.1.0_bin/jasperreports-server-pro-7.1.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/import-export.xml:196: Java returned: 137

Total time: 6 minutes 57 seconds
Checking Ant return code: OK
```

Comment: Can you double-check what version of ANT do you use? It should be pre-installed in the War File Distribution ZIP. Should be 1.8.2 or +.

Comment: V. Spachynsky, thank you for your answer. The problem is solved. RAM memory was insufficient (I had 3G). With 5G, jasperReports server 7.1.0 works without problems.